# comparative or superlative

Tags: grammar

comparative or superlative ?

Is France ( a good / a better / the best ) choice to study overseas than Australia or America?

My answer :  Is France a better choice to study overseas than Australia or America ?

I think, it should be comparative because it is not comparing with more than two things

It is the same way , when we say " He is elder of the two brothers"  Not eldest

So here ( studying in France is compared with studying either country overseas like Australia , America or perhaps any other county else, i.e. comparing one location with another individually

Comment: It doesn't matter how many things are being compared: the superlative cannot take a "than" complement. It can take a complement specifying the class among which the thing is superlative - usually introduced by _of_, or _out of_.

Comment: The issue is whether you want to say "the best choice" or "a better choice than A or B".

Answer (score 3):

You are right.  The speaker is comparing France with Australia and America, so should use the comparative.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter how many things you're comparing something with. You use the superlative when you are comparing something to a group *it belongs to,* where that group contains at least two other things.

So "France is the best of the countries in Europe" is correct because France is one of the countries in Europe. "France is better than the countries in Europe" would be incorrect.

But this is also correct, and has the same meaning: "France is better than the other countries in Europe." In that case, you're comparing France to a group of things ("the other countries in Europe") that *excludes* France. Without further context, "France is the best of the other countries in Europe" would be incorrect.

At the same time, you would say "He is the elder of the two brothers," since "the two brothers" contains only one thing other than him. But you would say "the eldest of the three brothers" because in that case there are *two* other brothers in the group.

In this case, you're comparing France with America and Australia, neither of which are France. So "Is France a better choice to study overseas than Australia or America?" is correct. But it would still be correct if you asked: "Is France a better choice to study overseas than Australia, America, the UK, or South Africa?"